# Hash table didn't return correct value by it's Index

Tags: c, file, hash, hashmap

I have this csv file contain people contact:

```
NAME, NUMBER, ADDRESS, EMAIL
Kevin Mahendra, +62 812-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Anggrek Merah 3, kevinitsnovember@gmail.com
Adwi Lanang, +62 821-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Ruhui Rahayu, adwilanang@gmail.com
Wasis Sirutama, +62 813-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Pramuka 6 25, wasisnaruto@gmail.com
Alief Dean, +62 811-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Padat Karya, aliefdean@gmail.com
Baharudin Nuri, +62 813-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Ruhui Rahayu 1, baharudin008@yahoo.com
Yonggi Wijaya, +62 853-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.PM Noor Pondok S, yonggiwijaya@gmail.com
Artha Yoga, +62 822-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.A.Yani Gg.1, arthayoga97@gmail.com
Rusydi Nashier, +62 858-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Perjuangan No.90, rusydinashier@gmail.com
Andre Pieters, +62 822-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Villa Tamara No.1, azzahz@gmail.com
Paco Corleone, +62 816-XXXX-XXXX, Jln.Anggrek Merah 3, pacocorleone@gmail.com
```

And this is my C code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Number of buckets for TABLE
#define N 26

#define MAX 50

typedef struct Contact
{
    char name[MAX];
    char number[MAX];
    char address[MAX];
    char email[MAX];
    struct Contact* next;
} 
Contact;

void searching_contact(FILE *file);
void load_hash_table(FILE **file);
unsigned int hash(const char *name);

// Hash table
Contact *table[N];

int main(void)
{  
    // OPEN CSV FILE AS append and read mode
    FILE *file = fopen("contacts.csv", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error open file!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    searching_contact(file);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}    

void searching_contact(FILE *file)
{

    char name[MAX];

    printf("Search Name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);
    fflush(stdin);

    // Load csv file into hash table first    
    load_hash_table(&file);

    // Get index number by calling hash function
    int hashIndex = hash(name);
    printf("\n\nIndex number we get from searching: %i\n", hashIndex);
    
    // Point to table that may contain the person
    Contact *cursor = table[hashIndex];
    
    // This will always print the last person
    printf("The name on the table: %s\n", cursor->name);

    // Keep traversing linked list in table
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        // If the person found, print the contact information
        if (strcmp(name, cursor->name) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s %s %s %s", cursor->name, cursor->number, cursor->address, cursor->email);
        }
        else
        {
            // If not the person, but in the same table, go to the next linked list
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    printf("Not found!\n");
}

// FUNCTION TO LOAD CSV FILE INTO HASH TABLE
void load_hash_table(FILE **file)
{
    Contact *new = malloc(sizeof(Contact));
    if (new == NULL)
        exit(1);

    /*
        "%[^,], "
        Empty space or space after above sign will remove spaces or newline (\n) on each string
        Just because, when we try to use hash function, the spaces or newline will also include
        And we want to remove them so when user searching by name it will produce same hash index
    */
    while(fscanf(*file, "%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %[^\n] ", new->name, new->number, new->address, new->email) == 4)
    {   
        // Skip header from CSV file   
        if (strcmp("NAME", new->name) == 0)
            continue;    
    
        // Get index number from hash function with People name as input
        int index = hash(new->name);

        // Try to print name and it's index in csv file for debugging
        printf("%s\n", new->name);
        printf("%i\n", index);
        
        /* 
            Create linked list point to WHAT inside Table[index]
            For very first struct, it points to NULL, then store it in Table
            Next struct, with the same Index number, it will point the first one
        */   
        new->next = table[index];
        table[index] = new;

        // Malloc for next fscanf
        Contact *new = malloc(sizeof(Contact));
        if (new == NULL)
            exit(1);
    }
}

// Hash function that will return index number from Table
unsigned int hash(const char *name)
{
    // TODO
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = toupper(*name++)))
    {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
    return hash % N;
}
```

So, Im trying to make a program where user can search people contact by name. And as you can see, i also want to exercise using **hash table/hash function**. So before searching, it will load all csv file into hash table (see `load_hash_table()`). But in the end, it always failed to found the person even though user already typing right name.

I try debugging using only printf.

First, at `load_hash_table()` function i print each name and it's index. And it's working correctly. It prints all the name in csv file and also correct index that produced by `hash` function.

Second, here's the problem. When i try to print inside `searching()` function. It produced correct and same **index** number. But when i print the name, it always print the last person on csv file, which is **Paco Corleone**. No matter what index number we put in **Table[]**, it always print that last person name.

I don't understand. It seems like the hash table lost all the data that have been loaded before when **while loop** inside `load_hash_table()` function is over. Maybe you'll see the problem when you run the code i gave. Please help me, i'm new in C language, thanks!

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)` invokes Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/3049655)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems:

1. The major problem is that there are two `Contact *new = malloc(sizeof(Contact));` lines. One inside the loop and one outside. They are two **different** variables. The `while` loop condition is using the one outside the loop. Hence the `fscanf` is writing to the same memory for every loop. One way to fix that is to make the second instance just `new = malloc(sizeof(Contact));`. Note that this loop has a memory leak as the last allocated node is lost - left to you as an exercise to fix.
2. `searching_contact` has an infinete loop as the `if (strcmp(name, cursor->name) == 0)` block is missing a `break`.